# Kohana ORM сортировка связанных моделей?

Tags: orm, php, kohana

Здравствуйте вообщем суть такова. Юзаю Kohana ORM. Есть таблица городов City есть таблица юзеров Users и таблица скажем продуктов Products. Между юзерами и городами есть связь `users.city_id` ну и соответсвенно между юзерами и продуктами `products.user_id`. Вопрос как правильно зная ID города вытащить все данные из таблицы Products связаных  примерно так `users.city_id->products.user_id`  да еще и отсортированных либо по ID продуктов либо по полю создания продукта `created_at`.  Сейчас у меня в таблице Products есть поле `city_id` по которому я и вытягиваю все данные связанные с городом.  Но это не совсем удобно так как при смене города у пользователья приходится искать все его записи в таблице Products и изменять там `city_id`. Собственно вопрос как правильно и оптимально это делать?

Прописал такие связи:

```
class Model_User extends Model_Auth_User {
protected $_belongs_to = array(
    'city' => array(
        'model' => 'city',
        'foreign_key' => 'city_id',
    )
    );
    protected $_has_many = array(
    'cartes' => array(
        'model' => 'carte',
        'foreign_key' => 'user_id',
    ),
    'roles' => array(
        'through' => 'roles_users'),
    );
}

class Model_City extends ORM {
    protected $_has_many = array(
    'users' => array(
        'model' => 'user',
        'foreign_key' => 'city_id',
    ),
    );
}

class Model_Carte extends ORM {
    protected $_belongs_to = array(
    'user' => array(
        'model' => 'user',
        'foreign_key' => 'user_id',
    ),
    );
}
```

Пробую вытащить все данные из модели Carte  которые связанны с  городом  так:

```
$city = ORM::factory('city', array('id'=>1));
foreach ($city->users->cartes->find_all() as $value)
{
    echo $value->name.' | ';
}
```

В итоге пустотота если вытакскивать всех юзиров принадлежащих к городу так : 
    $city->users->find_all()

Все работает или искать Данные из модели в через определенного юзера тоже работает: 
    $user->find_all()

А вот связка Город-Пользователь-Товар не рботает! ЧЯДНТ?

Посмотрел в дебаг и увидел что  конструкция вида `$city->users->cartes->find_all();`
Генерит вот такой вот sql запрос к бд

```
"SELECT `carte`.`id` AS `id`, `carte`.`user_id` AS `user_id`, `carte`.`name` AS `name`,  `carte`.`created_at` AS `created_at` FROM `cartes` AS `carte` WHERE `carte`.`user_id` IS NULL ORDER BY `created_at` DESC"
```

Тоесть в условии user_id у нас = NULL. Собственно вопрос такое вообще в ORM'е Кохановском возможно составлять цепочки из связей?

Answer (score 2):

Если вы правильно оформили связи, то:

```
$city->users->products->order_by('created_at')->find_all();
```

Связи должны быть такими:
City: `has_many` User
User: `belongs_to` City, `has_many` Product
Product: `belongs_to` User

Answer (score 0):

Я думаю вам просто надо прописать [связи](http://kohanaframework.org/3.2/guide/orm/relationships) в моделях `_has\_many_` и `_belongs\_to_`. Указать первичные и внешние ключи. Тогда выбирать будете примерно так: `ORM::Factory('User', $user_id)->cities->order\_by(...)` и т.д.

[Ko3 ORM. Изучаем заново?](http://brotkin.ru/2009/09/21/ko3-orm-izuchaem-zanovo/)